# java.io.FileNotFoundException: app/libs/perfectjpattern-core-1.0.0.jar (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, gradle, filenotfoundexception, perfectjpattern

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /app/libs/perfectjpattern-core-1.0.0.jar (No such file or directory)

I know that I need to install JAR. I do not understand how it came to this situation without making a change. It could have been because of the new Android Studio? Prew was using 2.1.alpha4

**gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
.....
compile files('libs/perfectjpattern-core-1.0.0.jar')
.....
}
```

Comment: Did you add the jar file in your project ?

Comment: Add some description please

Comment: Thanks, I know that I need to install JAR. I do not understand how it came to this situation without making a change. It could have been because of the new Android Studio? Prew was using 2.1.alpha4

Answer (score 0):

I installed jar files to find the solution.
I have no knowledge about how the JAR file is lost.
Thank you